# Selecting Internet Explorer <li> Object From <ul> Using Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, web-scraping, vba

I am trying to get the second option (the non-default option) to select (as in physically highlight) in IE from Excel VBA. I have tried numerous methods (by tag, by class, etc). Any ideas are appreciated. There are no IDs to go on, the code below is complete. It is a non-public website, however the source below is representative of the issue. My Google/searches here did not yield results. Please ask any follow-up needed.

```
<ul>
<li class="selected" title="Not What I Need"</li>
<li title="What I Need"</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get what you want:

```
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("selected")(0).NextSibling.getAttribute ("title")
```